# Decoding a JSON array that has no field name

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I have a simple JSON file like this.

```
{
    "january": [
        {
            "name": "New Year's Day",
            "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": true,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": true,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Martin Luther King Day",
            "date": "2019-01-21T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": true,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": true,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": true
        }
    ],
    "february": [
        {
            "name": "Presidents' Day",
            "date": "2019-02-18T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": false,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": false,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": false
        }
    ],
    "march": null
}
```

I'm trying to use Swift's `JSONDecoder` to decode these into objects. For that, I have created a `Month` and a `Holiday` object.

```
public struct Month {
    public let name: String
    public let holidays: [Holiday]?
}

extension Month: Decodable { }

public struct Holiday {
    public let name: String
    public let date: Date
    public let isNationalHoliday: Bool
    public let isRegionalHoliday: Bool
    public let isPublicHoliday: Bool
    public let isGovernmentHoliday: Bool
}

extension Holiday: Decodable { }
```

And a separate `HolidayData` model to hold all those data.

```
public struct HolidayData {
    public let months: [Month]
}

extension HolidayData: Decodable { }
```

This is where I'm doing the decoding.

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "holidays", withExtension: "json") else { return }
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Month.self, from: data)
    print(jsonData)
} catch let error {
    print("Error occurred loading file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
}
```

But it keeps failing with the following error.

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

I'm guessing it's failing because there is no field called `holidays` in the JSON file even though there is one in the `Month` struct.

How do I add the holidays array into the `holidays` field without having it in the JSON?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655562/how-to-exclude-properties-from-swift-4s-codable

Comment: That isn't a great JSON structure, to be honest.  Can you change it?  The month name should be a value, not a key.

Comment: Month structure is invalid.

Comment: @cwa Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I need include all the fields, not exclude any.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I tested with an online validator and it didn't return any errors though.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hmm...I see. I can have it changed. Would something like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/FAe3xZdK) be better?

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the JSON without writing custom decoding logic, you can do it as follows:

```
public struct Holiday: Decodable {
    public let name: String
    public let date: Date
    public let isBankHoliday: Bool?
    public let isPublicHoliday: Bool
    public let isMercantileHoliday: Bool?
}

try decoder.decode([String: [Holiday]?].self, from: data)
```

For that I had to make `isBankHoliday` and `isMercantileHoliday` `Optional` as they don't always appear in the JSON.

---

Now, if you want to decode it into the stucture that you introduced above, you'll have to write custom decoding logic:

```
public struct Month {
    public let name: String
    public let holidays: [Holiday]?
}

extension Month: Decodable { }

public struct Holiday {
    public let name: String
    public let date: Date
    public let isBankHoliday: Bool
    public let isPublicHoliday: Bool
    public let isMercantileHoliday: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case date
        case isBankHoliday
        case isPublicHoliday
        case isMercantileHoliday
    }
}

extension Holiday: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        isBankHoliday = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isBankHoliday) ?? false
        isPublicHoliday = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isPublicHoliday) ?? false
        isMercantileHoliday = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isMercantileHoliday) ?? false
    }
}

public struct HolidayData {
    public let months: [Month]
}

extension HolidayData: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let values = try container.decode([String: [Holiday]?].self)

        months = values.map { (name, holidays) in
            Month(name: name, holidays: holidays)
        }
    }
}

decoder.decode(HolidayData.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) However I'm getting a new error _The data couldn’t be read because it is missing_.  I uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bx2gnahzvddskdh/JSONDecoding.zip?dl=0) if you could please take a look.

Comment: @Isuru **Never** `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a `JSONDecoder` catch block. Always `print(error)`. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @vadian Got it! Fixed the issue. Thanks a ton to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure is quite awkward to be decoded, but it can be done.

The key thing here is that you need a `CodingKey` enum like this (pun intended):

```
enum Months : CodingKey, CaseIterable {
    case january
    case feburary
    case march
    // ...
}
```

And you can provide a custom implementation of `init(decoder:)` in your `HolidayData` struct:

```
extension HolidayData : Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var months = [Month]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Months.self)
        for month in Months.allCases {
            let holidays = try container.decodeIfPresent([Holiday].self, forKey: month)
            months.append(Month(name: month.stringValue, holidays: holidays))
        }
        self.months = months
    }
}
```

Also note that your structs' property names have different names from the key names in your JSON. Typo?

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I see. Someone else told me about the problem with the JSON structure too, I can have it changed. How about something like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/FAe3xZdK)?

Comment: @Isuru That's much better!

Comment: Gotcha! I'll change the JSON structure and give it a one more go.

Comment: Okay, I changed the JSON structure to that and replaced the `HolidayData` struct with a `Year` struct. It only has one property called `months` of `[Month]` type. Now I have to manually decode the month dictionaries in the `init` method of the `Year` struct, right? But my question is how do I define a `CodingKey` for the months array when there is no field called `months` in the JSON?

Comment: @Isuru I would declare `HolidayData` as a type alias of `[Month]`, and `Month` would have a `month: String` and a `holidays: [Holiday]` properties.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks. I updated my question to include all the new details btw.

Comment: @Isuru Your update to the question kind of invalidates a lot of the existing answers here... Could you please rollback your edit and post a new question? It would also be nice if you could accept an answer here.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to see my previous edits here? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Month structure does not match with the json.

Change month structure to something else like this:

```
public struct Year {
     public let January: [Holyday]?
     public let February: [Holyday]?
     public let March: [Holyday]?
     public let April: [Holyday]?
     public let May: [Holyday]?
     public let June: [Holyday]?
     public let July: [Holyday]?
     public let August: [Holyday]?
     public let September: [Holyday]?
     public let October: [Holyday]?
     public let November: [Holyday]?
     public let December: [Holyday]?
}

extension Year: Decodable { }
```

Note that it is not a best practice of how you can achieve what you want.

**Another way** is to change the json (*if you have access*) to match you structures:

```
{[
    "name":"january",
    "holidays": [
        {
            "name": "New Year's Day",
            "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": true,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": true,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Martin Luther King Day",
            "date": "2019-01-21T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": true,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": true,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": true
        }
    ]],[
    "name":"february",
    "holidays": [
        {
            "name": "Presidents' Day",
            "date": "2019-02-18T00:00:00-0500",
            "isNationalHoliday": false,
            "isRegionalHoliday": true,
            "isPublicHoliday": false,
            "isGovernmentHoliday": false
        }
    ]],[
    "name":"march",
    "holidays": null
    ]
}
```

Comment: I actually changed my JSON to look something exactly like that (`month` field instead of `name`). Now I'm having a new issue. I updated my original question above.