# Decoding an enum containing bools

Tags: ios, json, swift, boolean, jsonencoder

I have this JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "name": "January",
        "holidays": [
            {
                "name": "New Year's Day",
                "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00-0500",
                "type": {
                    "isNationalHoliday": true,
                    "isRegionalHoliday": true,
                    "isPublicHoliday": true,
                    "isGovernmentHoliday": true
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Martin Luther King Day",
                "date": "2019-01-21T00:00:00-0500",
                "type": {
                    "isNationalHoliday": true,
                    "isRegionalHoliday": true,
                    "isPublicHoliday": true,
                    "isGovernmentHoliday": true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "February",
        "holidays": [
            {
                "name": "Presidents' Day",
                "date": "2019-02-18T00:00:00-0500",
                "type": {
                    "isNationalHoliday": false,
                    "isRegionalHoliday": true,
                    "isPublicHoliday": false,
                    "isGovernmentHoliday": false
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "March",
        "holidays": null
    }
]
```

I created a `Month` struct to decode the dictionaries in the JSON.

```
public struct Month {
    public let name: String
    public let holidays: [Holiday]?
}

extension Month: Decodable { }
```

And an `Year` struct to contain them all.

```
public struct Year {
    public let months: [Month]
}

extension Year: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let values = try container.decode([Month].self)

        months = values
    }
}
```

My `Holiday` struct is a little more complex due to having an enum called `HolidayType` where I want to decode the values under the `type` field in the JSON.

```
public struct Holiday {
    public let name: String
    public let date: Date
    public let type: HolidayType
}

extension Holiday: Decodable { }

public enum HolidayType {
    case isNationalHoliday
    case isRegionalHoliday
    case isPublicHoliday
    case isGovernmentHoliday

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isNationalHoliday
        case isRegionalHoliday
        case isPublicHoliday
        case isGovernmentHoliday
    }
}

extension HolidayType: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self = try container.decode(HolidayType.self, forKey: .isNationalHoliday)
        self = try container.decode(HolidayType.self, forKey: .isRegionalHoliday)
        self = try container.decode(HolidayType.self, forKey: .isPublicHoliday)
        self = try container.decode(HolidayType.self, forKey: .isGovernmentHoliday)
    }
}
```

This is where I'm loading the file and decoding.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "holidays", withExtension: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        let year = try decoder.decode(Year.self, from: data)
        print(year.months)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error occurred decoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
} else {
    print("Error occurred loading file")
}
```

But it fails with the following error.

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
>   0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "holidays", intValue: nil),
>   _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "type", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "isNationalHoliday",
>   intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
>   Dictionary but found a number instead.", underlyingError:
>   nil))

I can't figure out how to fix this. I also uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o6zwew0e1yi0zyr/JSONEncodingEnums.zip?dl=0).

Comment: In addition to the enum problems mentioned below, note that the top-level object is an array, so you have to decode `[Month].self` and not `Year.self`.

Comment: @MartinR He has custom decoding for `Year`.

Comment: Your `Year` struct is redundant, just decode `let months = try decoder.decode([Month].self, from: data); print(months)`. And the `extension`s only to adopt `Decodable` are redundant, too. An empty extension only to adopt a protocol make sense if you are not the owner of the struct or class

Comment: @Sulthan: You are right, I did not notice that.

Comment: @vadian It makes sense to wrap months into a named type. I don't see a problem with correctly naming types, that's not redundancy.

Comment: @Sulthan IMHO it makes sense if there was another property `name` or `number` but not to wrap a single property on the top level of the hierarchy.

Comment: @vadian I consistently create new types just do wrap a `String`  (eg. `AccountNumber` or `Currency`) or a `Decimal` (e.g. `Amount`, `InterestRate`). You don't know what other methods can be declared on the given type and it's easier to pass `year: Year` instead of `year: [Month]`.

Comment: @Sulthan I understand but (at the moment) there is no `year` key in the JSON...

Comment: ... and the `singleValueContainer` struct comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713939/decoding-a-json-array-that-has-no-field-name/56714196#56714196) of the OP's previous question where the meaning was completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an enum to represent multiple booleans. If you want to keep your types without change, I would recommend using an `OptionSet` with custom decoding:

```
struct Year: Decodable {
    let months: [Month]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        months = try container.decode([Month].self)
    }
}

struct Month: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let holidays: [Holiday]?
}

struct Holiday: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let date: Date
    let type: HolidayType
}

struct HolidayType: OptionSet, Decodable {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let national = HolidayType(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let regional = HolidayType(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let `public` = HolidayType(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let government = HolidayType(rawValue: 1 << 3)

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self = try CodingKeys.allCases
            .filter { try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: $0) }
            .map { $0.type }
            .reduce([] as HolidayType) { $0.union($1) }
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case isNationalHoliday
        case isRegionalHoliday
        case isPublicHoliday
        case isGovernmentHoliday

        var type: HolidayType {
            switch self {
            case .isNationalHoliday:
                return .national
            case .isRegionalHoliday:
                return .regional
            case .isPublicHoliday:
                return .public
            case .isGovernmentHoliday:
                return .government
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or, instead of custom parsing, you can translate your types using a computed variable:

```
struct Holiday: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let date: Date
    private let type: HolidayTypeHolder
    var types: [HolidayType] {
        return type.types
    }
}

enum HolidayType: String {
    case national, regional, `public`, `government`
}

private struct HolidayTypeHolder: Decodable {
    let isNationalHoliday, isRegionalHoliday, isPublicHoliday, isGovernmentHoliday: Bool

    var types: [HolidayType] {
        var types: [HolidayType] = []
        if isNationalHoliday {
            types.append(.national)
        }
        if isRegionalHoliday {
            types.append(.regional)
        }
        if isPublicHoliday {
            types.append(.public)
        }
        if isGovernmentHoliday {
            types.append(.government)
        }

        return types
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `OptionSet`s is a completely new territory for me. Never knew you could make them act like enums.

Comment: @Isuru More preciselly, you can make them act like `Set<enum>`. It wouldn't make much difference declaring enum `HolidayType` and then using `Set<HolidayType>` for the type.

Answer (score -1):

> "isNationalHoliday", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

`isNationalHoliday` is a bool value not an enum type , so on for `isRegionalHoliday, isPublicHoliday, isGovernmentHoliday`

You need

```
// MARK: - Element
struct Root: Codable {
    let name: String
    let holidays: [Holiday]?
}

// MARK: - Holiday
struct Holiday: Codable {
    let name: String
    let date: Date
    let type: TypeClass
}

// MARK: - TypeClass
struct TypeClass: Codable {
    let isNationalHoliday, isRegionalHoliday, isPublicHoliday, isGovernmentHoliday: Bool
}
```

---

```
let year = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data)
```