# How do I add an additional property to a Model?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a `Model` which conforms to `Content`:

```swift
import Vapor
import Fluent

final class User: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "user"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "email")
    var email: String

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, email: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

This can be fetched from the database and directly returned from a route, so the client receives the users as JSON.

Now I want to add an additional property to the user, which isn't stored in the database but a fixed value or just added after the user is loaded from the database:

```swift
final class User: Model, Content {
    // ...
    var someOther: String = "hello"
    // ...
}
```

or

```swift
final class User: Model, Content {
    // ...
    var someOther: String? // set later
    // ...
}
```

Now the problem is that this property is never added to the JSON, so the client only gets the user's `id` and `email` and *NOT* the `someProperty`. How do I fix this?

Comment: If the question is "How to exclude properties from Swift 4's Codable?" then the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655562/how-to-exclude-properties-from-swift-4s-codable

Comment: My problem is that the `someProperty` is NOT included in the result

Comment: May we have a look at the piece of code where the coding takes place?

Comment: maybe Fluent by design encode only @Field properties?

Comment: @imike Is it Fluent that does the encoding? OP, maybe you should have a new struct that contains this new field also and then you map to this new struct when sent?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah, but that seems like a hack, I want to know if there is a proper solution

Comment: Actually I don't see it as a hack, you have one custom type that corresponds to what is persisted and here you need to use the data in a slightly different way so you create a new custom type for this scenario. And you can make this struct immutable also to make the solution even cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to send or receive data from your client that has a different representation from what your model has, it's common practice to define a custom type that you can then convert to and from the model type.

Given this, you would define a new `User.Response` type that conforms to `Content` instead of the `User` model, and return that from your route instead.

```
extension User {
    struct Response: Content {
        let id: UUID
        let email: String
        let otherValue = "Hello World"
    }
}


func user(request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<User.Response> {
    return User.find(UUID(), on: request.db).flatMapThrowing { user in
        guard let id = user.id else {
           throw Abort(.internalServerError, "User is missing ID")
        }

        return User.Response(id: id, email: user.email) 
    }
}
```

The reason the additional value that you added wasn't encoded from your model is because the default encoder for model types iterates over the field properties and  encodes those properties, so if you have a property that doesn't use one of the `ID`, `Field`, `Parent`, `Children`, or other field property wrappers, it won't be encoded.