# Assigning a fixed value to a variable in a struct

Tags: swift

I have a struct that is used when parsing JSON data. I want one of the fields, `name`, to be a fixed name, see below...

```swift
struct QuestionConfiguration: Codable, DisplayOrderable {
    var name: String? = "QuestionConfiguration"
    
    var isRequired: Bool
    var displayOrder: Int
    var title: String = ""
    var questions: [Question]
}
```

Each time, when I then try and access a QuestionConfiguration object, `name` is `nil`.

I have tried using an init(), with parameters and without.
I have tried `String?` and `String`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this so that `name` is the same for each object, without having to pass it to the object?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44655562/5133585) answer your question? It seems like you just want to exclude `name` from the `Codable` conformance.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't need to change `name`, just make it a `let` and it will be ignored.

Comment: Why is the ***fixed*** value mutable, and why is it optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by changing this line  -      `var name: String? = "QuestionConfiguration"` to this -     `let name = "QuestionConfiguration"`

Full code -

```
struct QuestionConfiguration: Codable, DisplayOrderable {
        let name = "QuestionConfiguration"
        
        var isRequired: Bool
        var displayOrder: Int
        var title: String = ""
        var questions: [Question]
    }
```

Note - If property is fixed then you should not call it as variable b'coz variable means it may change